# how to pass props to the route when using react router <Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

i'm trying to pass props to the route of the Link element. But when I open the invoiceDetails components, i says props is undefined.

Below is how I'm trying to pass the props. It is correctly setup because it goes to the InvoiceDetails component. I declared the routes in my index.js

```
<Link props={{name: 'jack', age: 25, city: 'Antwerp'}}to='/InvoiceDetails'><p>VIEW</p></Link>
```

And in the InvoiceDetails component

```
import React from 'react'
import DashboardHeader from '../dashboardHeader/dashboardHeader'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
function InvoiceDetails(){
console.log(props)
    return(
        <div className='w-10/12 bg-gray-300 float-right min-h-screen'>
          <div className='w-10/12 fixed z-50'>
.........
)
}
export default invoiceDetails
```

I would like to pass the props to the invoicedetails component using variables that I get from a global redux state. For now the static data is fine, the same principles apply I guess.

Comment: can you add your parent component where you passed InvoiceDetails Component to the question?

Comment: Looks like you need to use `to` to pass props: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass it by mentioning the props in `state`

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/InvoiceDetails",
    state: { name: 'jack', age: 25, city: 'Antwerp'}
  }}
/>
```

Read about it more [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link)

And to use it in your next component you have to either wrap your component with a react-router-dom HOC `withRouter` or use `useLocation` hook they have provided.

EX- In your second component -

```
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

function Child() {
 let data = useLocation();
 console.log(data); //state would be in data.state//
}
```

Comment: this makes sense, could you give me a push in the back on how to acces it in the invoicedetails component bc i'm getting a "cannot read .... of undefined" error when I try to log it in the component.

Comment: I realized i did not add that in my answer so i edited it @Jonas.D

Comment: thanks for the comment. I fixed it by passing props as a param in the function Child( 
props ) and then using it. 
You helped me on the right path and fixed my problem, enjoy your day!